# cuckoo sandbox - PID exit

Tags: malware, sandbox

I hope someone could help me I've played with cuckoo for a while however I've just done a new installation and it all works however it will not run the binary i would like to scan.  the PID exits after it is loaded? could anyone point me in the right direction as i cannot find what is wrong. the terminal then just times out and the VM closes without running the file.

attached is a screen shot of what i keep getting no matter what the binary is

using cuckoo 2.0 dev

cheers

TuGG
[image: cuckoo problem]

Comment: I would suspect something is going wrong with the injection and it's either not injecting properly, or it is but something is awry with cuckoomon. Can I ask which OS the guest VM is running?

Comment: Ty it is win 8.1 pro 64.  ive had it working with 1.2.  I get no errors in the debug at all it just opens and closes when the file is injected